# How to select duplicate values from table using Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

MyTable contains **Col1** which has Duplicate values.

How to select Duplicate Values from my table using Linq

My table is as follows

Table 1

```
Col1      Col2 
 1         A
 1         B
 1         C
 2         D
 2         E
 3         F
 3         G
 4         H
```

Till now I can only select Distinct  values from  Table

```
List<int> MyList=Table1.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select(row => row.Field<int>("Col1"))
                   .Distinct().ToList();
```

Please help

Comment: Can you please show some code how the cols and your table are implemented?

Answer (score 2):

```
List<int> MyList = Table1.AsEnumerable()
                         .GroupBy(row => new {
                                             Col1 = row.Field<int>("Col1"),
                                             Col2 = row.Field<string>("Col2")
                                         })
                         .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                         .Select(g => g.Key.Col1)
                         .ToList();
```